# Borrowing from Weak<T>

Tags: rust

I feel like `rc::Weak` could use a (sort of) `AsRef` trait implementation. I'm trying to borrow some shared content from a weak pointer, but this won't compile:

```
use std::rc::Weak;

struct Thing<T>(Weak<T>);


impl<T> Thing<T> {
  fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    self.0.upgrade().map(|rc| {
      rc.as_ref()
    })
  }

  // For clarity, without a confusing closure
  fn unwrapped_as_ref(&self) -> &T {
    self.0.upgrade().unwrap().as_ref()
  }
}
```

I understand why: the upgraded `Rc` does not survive the `as_ref` call. However it seems to me that it is perfectly sound. A possible magic trick using `unsafe` that does compile:

```
impl<T> Thing<T> {
  fn unwrapped_as_ref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
    let rc = self.0.upgrade().unwrap();
    unsafe {
      std::mem::transmute(rc.as_ref())
    }
  }
}
```

So:

- Are there any downsides to this solution? Is it sound? Can you think of a simpler alternative?
- Would it make sense to implement a `as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>` in the standard library?

Comment: I might be missing something crucial, but it seems to me that this can’t possibly be sound. As soon as your `as_ref` function exits the upgraded reference is destroyed, so there is no guarantee that the data is not freed, you can’t have a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t borrow from a *weak* reference, you just can’t. It’s weak, it does not guarantee that the underlying object exists (that’s why `upgrade()` returns an `Option`). And even if you were lucky and the value was still alive at the point you accessed it through the weak reference (`upgrade()` returned `Some`), it can be freed the next moment, as soon as the `upgrade`d reference goes out of scope.

In order to get a reference to the underlying value you need *something* that will keep it alive (e.g. a strong reference), but this means you’ll have to return it along with the reference.

Comment: Your answer is mostly on point, but [`upgrade()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.upgrade) does (potentially) convert a `Weak` into an `Rc`, so OP isn't trying to "borrow from a weak pointer".

Comment: @Shepmaster As far as I understand, what OP is _ultimately_ trying to do is borrow from a weak reference. As an intermediate step it is (potentially) converted to `Rc` but this can’t possibly help, unless I can’t see something obvious.

Comment: It looks like I am ultimately trying to borrow from a weak reference. I guess what I'd need to do is something like `as_ref(&self) -> ThingRef<T>` where I return a wrapper type like `ThingRef(Rc<T>)` implementing `AsRef<T>`.

Comment: @rvidal `Rc<T>` implements `Deref` and `AsRef<T>`, so maybe you just want to return that?

Comment: Indeed, just return the `Rc`.